# Reloading a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I can't find the correct method on how to reload a modal view controller from within itself. I'm developing a very simple UI based app but I'm not sure how to do this.

I open the modal view with the following:

```
MainView *mainmview = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"submod" bundle:nil];
    mainmview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self mainmview animated:YES];
```

and then can dismiss it depending on iOS version. However this has no effect when used on what i need to be a simple restart button. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement your own "refresh" functionality - define a "refresh" method inside the modal view controller's class and do whatever needs to be done inside it - if for instance you have a tableview that requires a reload or to refresh your views depending on new data, etc...